# Gazebo service call through network fails

Tags: gazebo

I run a Gazebo server on one machine and try to call a Gazebo service from a different machine in the same network.

There is a bidirectional communication between the two machines (i.e. ping works from both sides).

`Gazebo transport`'s discovery mechanism seems to work, because I receive the topics and services on the second machine :

```bash
$ gz service -l
/gazebo/resource_paths/add
... (other topics)
/world/multicopter/list_parameters
```

However, when I try to call a service, it fails :

```bash
$ gz service -s /world/multicopter/list_parameters --reqtype gz.msgs.Empty --reptype gz.msgs.ParameterDeclarations --timeout 2000 --req ''
Service call timed out
```

**Questions:** Has someone already tried this? Do you have any idea **why** the service request times out?

Edit:

- the `GZ_PARTITION` is set to similar value in both machines
- Topics are detected (`gz topic -l` outputs the list of topics) but not received (`gz topic -e -t /foo` outputs nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue !

`gz-transport` answers service requests using TCP (unlike the discovery, which uses UDP multicast).

This means that `gz-transport` has to choose a network interface from your computer ([I think it is done here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/blob/c958aec699bdf97690be0ad84a6e8efa6ec7b308/src/NetUtils.cc#L126-L158)), but you can force this choice by setting `GZ_IP`.

In my case, gazebo was using an interface that had no route toward the "client" machine. The two machines communicate through the network 10.0.0.0/24 (respectively `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2`).

To solve it, I simply set the interface I want to use on each machine :
Machine 1 :

```sh
export GZ_IP=10.0.0.1
```

Machine 2 :

```sh
export GZ_IP=10.0.0.2
```

> tip : Set `GZ_VERBOSE=1` to receive debug information and see which interface is being used by Gazebo ! :)

Answer (score 0):

gz-transport has the notion of partitions which allows you to isolate some topics/services from others. One of the constituents of the partition name is the host name as mentioned in https://gazebosim.org/api/transport/12/nodestopics.html#autotoc_md23. Since you're trying to communicate across different machines, you'll need to set the partition name to be identical in both hosts. You'd do this by setting the `GZ_PARTITION` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @azeey !
I already set the `GZ_PARTITION` env variable to the same value on both machines, as it is used in the discovery mechanism also, and I correctly receive existing topics and services on the "client" machine (`gz service -l` works fine). 
Even in the same Gazebo partition it appears the service request fails.

My call is that the "discovery" and "service answer" packets are different in term of networking, but I can't find the difference.